# Is it possible to search word in terminal?

Tags: linux

---

I had doubt is it possible to search the matching of words(i.e in the below image i want to search word month)using terminal.How can i search it using LINUX command.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use grep command to extract the words you want as follows :

> grep --color -i -E "{regex|word}" {filename}

Otherwise open the vim editor and press `:` then type `hlsearch` to set the searching words to be highlighted if they are matching. Now open the file with vim editor and start searching.

for detailed steps, follow this [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_all_search_pattern_matches)